# Access user data associated with event provided using TraceLoggingWrite

Tags: c++, windows, msdn, etw

I am able to generate tracelogging events from my application(able to view them in Windows Performance Analyzer) using this [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/tracelogging/tracelogging-record-and-display-tracelogging-events). 
The event emitted is as follows

```
HRESULT CTracelogger::PublishEvent(void *pData)
{
    if (pData)
    {
        EVENT_H sHEvent = *(static_cast<EVENT_H *>(pData));
        TraceLoggingWrite(g_hEventProvider,
            "HEvent",
            TraceLoggingStruct(5, "HEventData"),
            TraceLoggingUInt32(sHEvent.m_eEventType, "eEventType"),
            TraceLoggingUInt32(sHEvent.m_uiVersion, "Version"),
            TraceLoggingUInt32(sHEvent.m_uiPid, "Pid"),
            TraceLoggingUInt32(sHEvent.m_uiSize, "Size"),
            TraceLoggingWideString(sHEvent.m_wszHName, "HName")
        );
    }
    return S_OK;
}
```

I am trying to consume the same events in a different application by writing a custom consumer, the consumer is receiving the events(as the corresponding provider GUID events are being received). I am trying to access the user data associated with the event using TdhGetProperty() as shown in documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/etw/using-tdhgetproperty-to-consume-event-data) but the function TdhGetEventInformation() is failing with ERROR_NOT_FOUND if the variable buffersize is initialized to 0 and fails with error ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER if buffersize is initialized to a non-zero value.

Is the above approach taken correct to retrieve the data associated with the tracelogging event? 
If yes, then why TdhGetEventInformation() is failing?

```
VOID WINAPI CEventLogger::EventRecordCallback(PEVENT_RECORD pEvent)
{
    DWORD status = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    PTRACE_EVENT_INFO pInfo = NULL;
    char msgbuf[4096];
    DWORD BufferSize = 0;


    status = TdhGetEventInformation(pEvent, 0, nullptr, pInfo, &BufferSize);

    if (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == status)
    {
        pInfo = (TRACE_EVENT_INFO*)malloc(BufferSize);
        if (pInfo == NULL)
        {
            OutputDebugString("Failed to allocate memory for event info");
            status = ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            OutputDebugString("successful memory allocation");
        }
        // Retrieve the event metadata.

        status = TdhGetEventInformation(pEvent, 0, nullptr, pInfo, &BufferSize);
    }

    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != status)
    {
        sprintf_s(msgbuf, "TdhGetEventInformation failed status[%d], buffersize[%d]", status, BufferSize);
        OutputDebugString(msgbuf);
    }
    else
    {
        sprintf_s(msgbuf, "TdhGetEventInformation successful, buffersize[%d]", BufferSize);
        OutputDebugString(msgbuf);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code above looks reasonable. My guess is that the problem is with your call to OpenTrace. By default (for backwards-compatibility with very old code), OpenTrace assumes that your callback wants to receive an `EVENT_TRACE` structure. However, your callback wants to receive an `EVENT_RECORD`. To tell OpenTrace to use the newer `EVENT_RECORD` format, you have to set `ProcessTraceMode` to `PROCESS_TRACE_MODE_EVENT_RECORD`.